# Java калькулятор

Tags: java, equals

Калькулятор принимает от пользователя выражение и пишет его в строку которую я хочу проверить на наличие римских цифр и заменить их на арабские. Калькулятор принимает на вход числа до 10. Только вот не могу понять в каком месте ошибка, мне кажется ошибка логическая.

вот мой код:

```
public class Main {
    private static final char exitCharacter = '!';
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DataReader reader = new DataReader(exitCharacter);
        while (true) {
            try {
                reader.read();
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                continue;
            }
            if (reader.isExitFlag()) {
                System.out.println("В выражении пристутствует знак выхода: " + exitCharacter);
                System.out.println("Завершение программы.");
                break;
            }
            double result = Calculator.calculate(reader.getVar1(), reader.getVar2(), reader.getOper());
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }
}
 
 
import java.util.Scanner;
 
public class DataReader {
 
    private int number1;
    private int number2;
    private char operation;
    private boolean exitFlag;
    private char exitCharacter;
    private char resultChar;
 
    public DataReader(char exitCharacter) {
        this.exitCharacter = exitCharacter;
        this.resultChar = '=';
    }
 
 
    public void read() {
 
        Integer[] arabic = {10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
        String[] roman = {"X", "IX", "VIII", "VII", "VI", "V", "IV", "III", "II", "I"};
 
        System.out.println("Введите выражение, состоящее из двух целых чисел от 0 до 10, знака операции и знака равно (напр. 2+2=): ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        //StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String text = scanner.nextLine();
        if (text.indexOf(exitCharacter) != -1) {
            exitFlag = true;
            return;
        }
 
        try {
            if ((text.charAt(text.length() - 1) != resultChar)) {
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }
 
            text = text.substring(0, text.length() - 1);
            String[] blocks = text.split("[+-/*]");
 
            // проверяем, входит ли строка blocks[0] в массив строк массива "roman"
            boolean flag = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < roman.length; i++){
                if (roman[i].equals(blocks[0]) || roman[i].equals(blocks[1])){
                    flag = true;
                }
                //flag = true, значит будем иметь дело с римскими обозначениями
                if(flag){
                    number1 = romanToNumber(blocks[0]);
                    number2 = romanToNumber(blocks[1]);
                } else {
                    number1 = Integer.parseInt(blocks[0]);
                    operation = text.charAt(blocks[0].length());
                    number2 = Integer.parseInt(blocks[1]);
 
                }
            }
            if ((number1 > 10 || number1 < 0) || (number2 > 10 || number2 < 0)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Неверный формат данных");
        }
    }
 
    private static int romanToNumber(String roman) {
        if (roman.equals("I")) {
            return 1;
        } else if (roman.equals("II")) {
            return 2;
        } else if (roman.equals("III")) {
            return 3;
        } else if (roman.equals("IV")) {
            return 4;
        } else if (roman.equals("V")) {
            return 5;
        } else if (roman.equals("VI")) {
            return 6;
        } else if (roman.equals("VII")) {
            return 7;
        } else if (roman.equals("VIII")) {
            return 8;
        } else if (roman.equals("IX")) {
            return 9;
        } else if (roman.equals("X")) {
            return 10;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
 
    public int getVar1() {
        return number1;
    }
 
    public int getVar2() {
        return number2;
    }
 
    public char getOper() {
        return operation;
    }
 
    public boolean isExitFlag() {
        return exitFlag;
    }
}
 
public class Calculator {
    private Calculator(){}
 
    public static double calculate(int number1, int number2, char operation){
        int result = 0;
        switch (operation){
            case '+': result = number1 + number2; break;
            case '-': result = number1 - number2; break;
            case '*': result = number1 * number2; break;
            case '/': result = number1 / number2; break;
            default:throw  new IllegalArgumentException("Не верный знак операции");
        }
        return result;
    }
 
}
```

Вынести operation = text.charAt(blocks[0].length()); за цикл for не помогает калькулятор отказывается работать с римскими цифрами и выкидывает исключение

```
2+II=
Неверный формат данных
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос описание ошибки.

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            if (roman[i].equals(blocks[0]) || roman[i].equals(blocks[1])){
                flag = true;
            }
            //flag = true, значит будем иметь дело с римскими обозначениями
            if(flag){
                number1 = romanToNumber(blocks[0]);
                number2 = romanToNumber(blocks[1]);
            } else {
                number1 = Integer.parseInt(blocks[0]);
                operation = text.charAt(blocks[0].length());
                number2 = Integer.parseInt(blocks[1]);

            }
```

Неправильная логика. Вы устанавливаете флаг после проверки на `"X"` и начинаете парсить операнды как десятичные. Если операнды - римские, но не `"X"`, происходит ошибка.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался.

Comment: @ОлегКутовенко Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.